# Netbeans 6.8 no profiler?

Tags: netbeans, 64-bit, fedora, java

I wanted to profile my project on a different system but the netbeans installed there 
doesn't seem to have the profiler available.
This is `java -version` on that box; (1.6.0_18)

`OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8.3) (fedora-46.1.8.3.fc13-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)`

Could the configuration be the reason, or I have to fiddle with netbeans settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `Tools->Plugins`, check the "Installed" tab. If there is no "Java Profiler" plugin there, you may need to install it through the "Available" tab. Or you may need to activate it if it's in the "Installed" tab, but not marked as active.